# How is complex analysis relevant to other areas of mathematics?

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question

I'm going to do a math PhD next year. My main interests in mathematics are composition algebra, algebraic topology, and group theory.

Now I have the opportunity to take a one-semester course in complex analysis, but I am not sure if it is relevant to my research interests.

My understanding of complex analysis is that it is mostly about Laurent series, Cauchy's integral theorem, residue theorem, and evaluating weird-looking real integrals using these techniques. But I fail to see its connection to algebra.

I am sure that it is a beautiful theory and that it is also an important set of tools for applied mathematicians and engineers, but is there anything useful I can take from complex analysis as an algebraist?

Comment: It's crucial in number theory ....

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Analytic Number Theory...

Comment: Consider $(-1)^x$ where $x>0$ is a real number.

Comment: It's a very big help in transform theory (Fourier analysis) as it helps calculate some nasty real valued integrals.

Comment: You fail to see connections, I fail to see boundaries. Mathematics is _one_ science, personal limitations and the (non-scientific) conditions of mathematical research enforce specialization. That's all. The fundamental theorem of algebra: every non-constant polynomial has a complex zero. One line proof: otherwise, $1/p(z)$ would be a bounded, analytic function.

Comment: Complex analysis is black magic. The proof of FTA (mentioned in above comment) becomes trivial thanks to a certain Liouville's theorem in complex analysis. There is "Complex analysis in number theory" by A. Karatsuba to further elaborate on the usefulness of complex analysis. As you may already guess, lots to do with prime number theory and the zeta function.

Comment: There is a type of algebra called $C^*$-algebras. Although algebras tend to be as much the domain of functional analysts as algebraists, $C^*$-algebras take on enough of complex analysis's niceness that their study is more algebra than analysis, once you learn the basic theorems.

Comment: Complex analysis and algebraic topology can view the same idea in different ways. Winding numbers exist in both fields, and you can use contour integrals to help you determine the first homology group of a space. Covering maps from topology are closely related to Riemann surfaces of certain functions (like $e^z$ gives an infinite covering of $\mathbb{C} - 0$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main interests show that you want to become a professional mathematician. In these circles everyone will take it for granted that you know the basics of complex analysis. Computing real integrals using all sorts of residue tricks does not belong to the mainstream of this field.